# How to get the sum of all textbox of a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, textbox, datatables

I have one datatable which has 7 columns. Last column has textboxes where user can enter the payment amount. Below is the HTML code for the same:

```
<table id="multiple-account-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="border-class">
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            <th>Alias</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Total Due</th>
            <th>Payment Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                <th></th>
                 <th id="payment-footer"></th>
             </tr>
          </tfoot> 
</table>
```

The rows of table are getting generated dynamically using datatable method of jquery.

Below is the HTML code for textbox present in last column:

```
<input type="number" id="payement-textbox" class="payment" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" name="payment-textbox" placeholder="--"/>
```

My requirement is that, when user will enter an amount inside any of textbox, then sum of textbox should update at the same time. The sum of payment amount in all textbox is being displayed in the table footer. It is not compulsory for user to enter amount in all textboxes. So sum will be displayed for all the rows where user have entered any value.

I wrote jQuery code which is working fine.Only problem is that if user reduce the value in textbox then sum doesnt get reduced accordingly. For example ,suppose user have entered 50 in first textbox and 100 in second textbox then sum will be shown up "150" which is correct.

But if user change the value of second textbox to 50, them sum will be shown up "150" instead of "100".

Below is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on("blur paste",'input.payment', function(event) {
  //taking value of sum which is initially zero

    var temp = $("#payment-footer").html(); 
    var sum = parseFloat(temp);
    if( $(this).val() != ""){
    var sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
     $("#payment-footer").html('$'+sum); 
  }
});
```

Comment: use `input` instead of blur and paste. `$(document).on("input",'input.payment', function(event) {` also check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182439/count-input-values)

Comment: !!! note that the use of jquery to calculate a sum for payment is not a good solution. on every change you should call and ajax post to send ids of selected, and get the response:"sum" then showing it like  $("#payment-footer").html('$'+sum);

Comment: if you are using Jquery datatable plugin, then this can be helpful for you.. **[link](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/mzbw72js/20/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate loop through all the textboxes of datatable and make sum of it.

```
$(document).on("blur paste",'#multiple-account-table input.payment', function(event) {  
      var sum = 0;
      //Loop through all the textboxes of datatable and make sum of the values of it.
      $.each('#multiple-account-table input.payment',function(){
        var sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
      });
      //Replace the latest sum.
      $("#payment-footer").html(sum); 
    });
```